# Reading ID with For Loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, syntax-error

I know it's a syntax error but how can i read the ID which includes vat then the i of the for loop and continues with Email

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [id^="vat"[i]"Email"]`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: You need to provide more details. What is the input data? What output so you want? What code you tried?

Comment: I posted the For Loop.. I just need to read an ID and each ID starts with vat

Comment: This is not c# syntax and you tagged question as c#

Comment: Yes im sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your given information and without having more information, I would change the code this way:

```
for (i = 1; i < $('[id^="vat"]').length; i++) {
   $('[id^="vat' + i + 'Email"]').each(function () {
      $(this).val($wteemail.val());
   });
}
```